# jQuery plugin not working in Joomla 3 module

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to implement a jQuery plugin for converting tabs to responsive accordion in my Joomla 3 module. The plugin is called **Easy Responsive Tabs to Accordion** (https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion). I have correctly included the required css and js files in the module but it's not firing up the plugin for me.

In the module's `tmpl/default.php`, I've included the scripts as below:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mytest/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js');
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mytest/js/jquery-1.9.1.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mytest/css/mytheme/easyResponsiveTabs.css');
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs();
});
</script>
```

I also have the correct HTML markup in `tmpl/default.php` as shown in the docs.

When I download and run the plugin, it works fine but when I integrate it in Joomla, it fails. I may be missing some simple steps while integrating it but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Go to Console in your Browser (F12), and see if have any javascript errors. Maybe is having a conflict.

Comment: Have you got any other extensions or modules running on the page? I have found in the past they call jquery and that causes issues. Try putting jquery into "No Conflict Mode"

Comment: @tim.baker The other modules running on the page are Joomla's built-in modules. There are no 3rd party modules on the page. I've also tried "no conflict". Still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, check in Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug (whatever your browser uses) to see if the 3 files you have imported are actually being imported. There is nothing wrong with the way you have done that, but always good to check. Then, replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs();
});
</script>
```

with the following:

```
$document->addScriptDeclaration('$("#horizontalTab").easyResponsiveTabs();');
```

I think it's the way you were calling the plugin so pretty sure the code above will sove the issue

**Update:**

Just realised that you're using Joomla 3.0, so rather than importing jQuery the way you have done so, use the following instead:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

make you insert it before the other scripts. This uses the Joomla 3.x coding standards to import jQuery in *noConflict* mode.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes all those 3 files are correctly imported. I checked it with Firebug. I've also tried your suggestion above but still does not seem to work.

Comment: Adding `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` with no-conflict jquery seems to work fine. I can see no conflict jquery `jQuery.noConflict();` is already loaded in the header by default. So all I had to do was something like this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { jQuery('#tabs').easyResponsiveTabs({.....});`. This has worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include jquery library first:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mytest/js/jquery-1.9.1.js');
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mytest/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base().'modules/mod_mytest/css/mytheme/easyResponsiveTabs.css');
```

If don't solve, try to use jQuery no conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried everything as you've suggested above but still does not work.